# Oracle Apex or ORDS not recognizing images folder

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I've installed Oracle Apex 5 and configured ORDS through Tomcat however I'm getting the error as below:

`There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix path is correct. Your current path is /i/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guys I have finally managed to resolve it by changing the default images folder from /i/ to /images/ using reset_image_prefix.sql and copying images folder from apex folder to webapps

Comment: You could have also simply renamed "images" to "i" and moved it to the webapps folder. No need to run reset_image_prefix

Comment: @OlafurTryggvason please can you tell me where is the webapps folder is located ? I have the same issue

Comment: It's under your tomcat installation folder

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the images to the Tomcat directory?

> •Copy the contents of the <apex directory>/images folder to <Tomcat
>   directory>/webapps/i/.
>
> Where:
>
> •<apex directory> is the directory location of the Oracle Application
>   Express distribution.
>
> •<Tomcat directory> is the folder where Apache Tomcat is installed.

Oracle documentation link:
[1.8.4 Configuring Oracle Application Express Images](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37099_01/doc.20/e25066/install.htm#AELIG7227)

Comment: Yes I did copy the images to webapps/i/ in tomcat. http://localhost:8080/i/ also doesn't show anything it gives error 404

Comment: This is a link that should show an image : http://localhost:8080/i/apex_ui/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png

Comment: Thanks for your replies, this link also gives same error... 404 not found